# Named WPF control can't be found when added procedurally

Tags: c#, wpf

We are using a third party editing control (TxTextControl) that has various toolbars and other controls which can be attached to it.  This is done by placing the toolbars somewhere in the view and associating them by name.  It looks something like this:

```
<tx:RulerBar x:Name="rulerBar"/>
<tx:TextControl RulerBar="rulerBar"/>
```

This works fine when defined in XAML, but we have a scenario where we need to build this procedurally. For some reason when we try associate the RulerBar (or any other toolbars/controls) it throws an error that it can't locate the toolbar.  For example:

```
DockPanel dock = new DockPanel();
dock.Children.Add(new RulerBar { Name="rulerBar" });
dock.Children.Add(new TextControl { RulerBar = "rulerBar" });
```

I have also tried adding Loaded event handlers and deferred the RulerBar association until both controls were fully loaded but I still get the same error. Should this simply work, or is there some trick I'm missing?  Unfortunately name association is the only mechanism they provide, and we can't associate the controls by reference.

Comment: Do you have the directives available for you to `using` within your class?

Comment: @Adam, you mean do they implement IDisposable?  No they do not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Eyal Perry is correct with his diagnose of the problem. In order to make it work you should use the [`FrameworkElement.RegisterName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.registername(v=vs.110).aspx) method. Here's an example of how to use it:

```
DockPanel dock = new DockPanel();
var ruler = new RulerBar { Name = "rulerBar" };
dock.RegisterName(ruler.Name, ruler);
dock.Children.Add(ruler);
dock.Children.Add(new TextControl { RulerBar = "rulerBar" });
```

Answer (score 3):

In WPF, the XAML parsing process associates the value of an element's x:Name attribute with its name, enabling lookup by name.

So why does assigning the Name  property in XAML work? This is since the Name property is marked with an attribute which instructs the parser to treat it  like it treats an x:Name attribute.

Since you do not implement the same logic as the xaml parser does, you will have to do some additional coding in order for your code to work.. 
I myself did not know how to do that, but fortunately @Grx70 did.. see his answer.